# Strange behavior of wxPython control in Pycharm IDE

Tags: wxpython, pycharm

I'm learning wxPython 2.8 and Pycharm 1.2.1. (Python version - 2.6.6, Windows XP).
My first program (from http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#A_First_Application:_.22Hello.2C_World.22):

```
# hi.py
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ We simply derive a new class of Frame. """
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Show(True)
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Small editor')
app.MainLoop()
```

It runs OK when starting like: python hi.py .
But when it starting from PyCharm
there is no control TextCtrl on the Frame.
Why so?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of IDEs have problems running GUI applications from within. I recall similar issues in PyScripter and not really sure, Wing IDE? The only IDE which seems not to have any issues like this is Eclipse + PyDev, as far as I know.

Comment: Wingware IDE works fine with wxPython. I've been using it with wx for a couple years now.

Comment: @Mike Driscoll - Good to know. I am certain that some other IDE crashed every time I closed wxPython application, which was ran directly from the IDE.

Comment: I know that IDLE didn't get along with wx. When Wing runs the code, it does so in a separate process of some sort so there is no conflict.

Comment: @Mike Driscoll - Right! That is the one. So IDLE and PyScripter.